# Expand CSS Links with Icon

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, icons

I can add to a link an icon with CSS like a

CSS

`[href^="/path/"] {background-image: url(/icon-image.png);}`

for Links like

`<a href="/path/xyz/abc/test.html">Test</a>`

but it doens't work for links like

`<a href="test.html">Test</a>`

but this link lead to /path/xyz/abc/test.html, because test.html is located in /abc/

`a[href*="path"]` also don't work

My links mostly look like /path-x/path-y/path-z/, because the link often only to the index.php.

How to change the css-code for all links in the path /path/ which works also with the links like the second example.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is it possible to add the icon for links which don't include /path/, but the link  lead to /path/... like test.html or /path-y/path-z/test.html

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear but I'll try to answer whatever I can make out.

If your problem is that you can't get the proper css selector to work you can use

```
[href$=".html"]
```

to match all `href` attributes that end in `.html`. Now, if what you wanted was to apply the same style to all links, both those that have your `[href^="/path/"]` selector and those with other selectors, then just place them like this:

```
[href^="/path/"], [href$=".html"] {
    background-color: blue
}
```

I suggest you do some further reading of [attribute selectors on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). You can read how they work there and make your selectors the way you want them.

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors match the literal value of the attribute in the DOM. You cannot process the CSS the way you are wanting to.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--HTML File-->

<a href="http://home.com" id="logo">Your logo</a>
<!--CSS File-->
#logo {
background-image: url(images/logo.png);
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 981px;
height: 180px;
}
```

Comment: Even though it's hard to make sense out of the question, this answer has nothing to do with it. It's about [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)